# Join operators and commutativity

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I am doing some relational algebra exercizes. On a teacher slide I saw a thing that makes me think that there can be an error.
I think, the third JOIN, should be

```
JOIN 'Farmacia' as F
ON 'D'.'idCF' = 'F'.'idFì
```

instead of

```
JOIN 'Farmacia' as F
ON 'F'.'idFì = 'D'.'idCF'
```

Using this last command you will join Farmacia on itself, isn't it?

The slide question says:

> Which pharmacy does sell drug X of phramaceutic company Y?

[image]

Comment: The command is correct. Order of the columns in the ON part of the statement doesn't influence how the `JOIN` itself is done.

Comment: fill an answer so you can get the green mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the columns in the ON part of the statement doesn't influence how the JOIN itself is done.

This:

```
SELECT t1.columnA, t2.columnB
FROM Table1 t1
   JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID = t2.ID
```

will yield the same results as this:

```
SELECT t1.columnA, t2.columnB
FROM Table1 t1
   JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
```

The self-join you described would have been something like this:

```
SELECT t1.columnA, t2.columnB
FROM Table1 t1
   JOIN Table1 t2 ON t1.managerID = t2.employeeID
```

Comment: Sorry, just another question: what about the order of joins?

Comment: Do you mean the order of the tables in the JOINS? When writing queries, you typically add the tables in the order they relate to one another. If you have a chain of related tables, I do believe it's good practice using the chain in proper order. Some query tools might throw errors if the JOIN you are writing relies on a not-yet-referenced table. However, when you actually run the query, I'd like to think the engine would figure it all out.