# Commutativity of Inner Join

Tags: sql

I read from [this answer (click)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20032431/1149595), the following conditional statements

```
Invoices.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
```

and

```
Customers.CustomerID=Invoices.CustomerID
```

are identical because it produces the same result set.

Now, my problem is about commutativity of inner join. I have tried both of the following approaches and they produce the same result set (except for the column order).

### `Customers` table first

```
use MMABooks
select *
from Customers
    inner join Invoices
on Invoices.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
where Customers.CustomerID=10
```

### `Invoices` table first

```
use MMABooks
select *
from Invoices
    inner join Customers
on Invoices.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID
where Invoices.CustomerID=10
```

### Questions

1. Is inner join commutative by design?
2. Is there a best practice that suggest or prefer one approach over the other one? I mean, which approach should I use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be really weird if they didn't produce the same result. Did you expect a difference?

A best practice is to start with the table from which you select most of the columns.

You do have to worry about the order when you work with `LEFT` or `RIGHT JOINS`.